# Show right values on axis

Tags: r, plot

I have this `Data.Frame` (`mydf`):

```
year   total
1999   3967
2002   580
2005   5203
2008   2406
```

and to display it, I just run:

`plot(mydf)`

However I can see on the x-axis (`year`) the labels:

`2000 2002 2004 2006 2008`

How can I tell to `plot/axis` to display only the four expected values: `1999,2002,2005,2008` without trying to infer the sequence?

Comment: Use the `xaxt="n"` and then with `axis` you can change the labels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3732271/akrun) suggest, you can use:

```
plot(mydf, xaxt = "n")
axis(1, at = mydf$year)
```

Data:

```
mydf <- structure(list(year = c(1999L, 2002L, 2005L, 2008L), total = c(3967L, 
580L, 5203L, 2406L)), .Names = c("year", "total"), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If we are using `ggplot`, we can also try

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
mydf %>% 
    mutate(year = as.character(year)) %>% 
    ggplot(., aes(x=year, y = total)) + 
             geom_point() + 
             scale_x_discrete(labels = mydf$year) +
             theme_bw()
```

[image]

#### data

```
mydf <- structure(list(year = c(1999L, 2002L, 2005L, 2008L), total = c(3967L, 
580L, 5203L, 2406L)), .Names = c("year", "total"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```